# Images loading in exported JAR, but not when running from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing, executable-jar

I've seen lots of people having the same issue about images that are loaded when running in Eclipse, but not when running from the exported JAR. I was having this problem until I found the right fix. Now I'm having an issue where the images are loaded and the program works perfect when running from a newly exported, runnable JAR, but not in Eclipse! It's worth noting that I updated Java before hand on my machine!

Here's a screenshot of my project:
[image]

It was running perfectly fine in Eclipse, until I worked out how to export a runnable JAR properly and now it doesn't! The Assets folder is made to be a source folder and that Image class seen on line 19 uses the following code:

```
public Image(String path)
{
    
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    w = image.getWidth();
    h = image.getHeight();
    // Reads all the pixel data into a 1D array
    p = image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);
}
```

The full error is viewable in the screenshot, but the exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1356)
    at rawGE/com.albionbrown.rawge.gfx.Image.<init>(Image.java:20)
    at coalDrop/com.albionbrown.ld48.MenuSprite.<init>(MenuSprite.java:19)
    at coalDrop/com.albionbrown.ld48.Game.<init>(Game.java:44)
    at coalDrop/com.albionbrown.ld48.Game.main(Game.java:32)
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: Yes - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Comment: I can't see any `input` variable. For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue

Comment: The `input` variable is ok and populated at that point. I'm just curious is there some kind of include path that I need to configure for running within Eclipse?

Comment: Not an expert at eclipse, but this is hard to debug without a proper MRE

Comment: Understandable! It's worth noting I also updated my Java version before hand on my machine if that makes a difference? On JDK16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long while, I finally discovered what the issue was.

In my exported JAR (a little game library I was then importing into my game project), I have a class for loading images that used

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)
```

given `path` was a string to a real image. This worked fine when running test classes actually inside my game library project because I guess getResourceAsStream() uses a **localised root** being the root of the game library project.

So, my fix was to create two constructors for my image loading class (in the game library). One that still accepted file path strings and used getClass().getResourceAsStream(path), like so:

```
public Image(String path)
{
    loadImageResource(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
}

private void loadImageResource(InputStream path)
{
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(path);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and another for projects using the game library as an exported JAR, that accepted an InputStream object. This means that the method calling the Image constructor will need to run getClass().getResourceAsStream(path) itself (I guess then using that project as the root, rather than the exported JAR's root). Like so:

```
public Image(InputStream path)
{
    loadImageResource(path);
}

private void loadImageResource(InputStream path)
{
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(path);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```